# Error calling getIntent() from Broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I am trying to send an integer value from an Activity to a Broadcast receiver, Here is the method code in my Activity:

```
public void vibrator(View view){
    if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vibration ON",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(AddAlarm.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("vibrator",1);

    }
}
```

And now , from the Broadcast Receiver, when I try to invoke :

```
Intent receive = getIntent();
```

This is an error, but how to do this in the correct way ?

The code inside AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    int vibrator = intent.getIntExtra("vibrator", 1);

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, 
intent, 0);


    Uri alarmUri = 
RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null)
    {
        alarmUri = 
RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();


    //intent to call the activity which shows on ringing
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Time_Date.class);
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myIntent);

    //display that alarm is ringing
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Ringing...!!!", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            AlarmService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

    if(vibrator==1)
    {
        Log.w("the value I get is","given as"+vibrator);

    }


}
```

}

Comment: What is the error? Be specific pls @oblivion

Comment: why do you need getIntent() ? You will get the intent variable from onReceive method inside Broadcast Recever!

Answer (score 3):

> Error calling getIntent() from Broadcast receiver

`getIntent()` method is not from `BroadcastReceiver` class.

In `BroadcastReceiver` to get intent which is send using `sendBroadcast` method use  `onReceive` method second parameter which is `Intent` :

```
 @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       int vibrator=intent.getIntExtra("vibrator",1);
   }
```

Comment: I already use onReceive with another intent, so do you think this will work?

Comment: ` public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        int vibrator = intent.getIntExtra("vibrator", 1);

        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);


        Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if (alarmUri == null)
        {
            alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
        ringtone.play(); `

Comment: I ve edited the question, and added the AlarmReceiver class as well